# LINQ to group objects according to timestamp

Tags: c#, .net, linq, timestamp, grouping

I have a serial of object defined as:

```
public class Foo
{
           public DateTime Time {get;set;}
}
```

now I want to group objects(`IEnumerable<Foo>`) according to the time, e.g. I want to group them according to **hour or day or month**.

for example (group into hour):

```
group 1(13:00-14:00) : foo1, foo2, foo3
group 2(14:00-15:00): foo4, foo5
```

How to write LINQ over this? hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **don't** want to group the 13-14hr yesterday with the 13-14hr today, nor the 5th of this month with the 5th of last month etc. so you'll need to do something like:-

```
// splitting time up into hour intervals
fooList.GroupBy(f => f.Time.Date.AddHours(f.Time.Hour))

// splitting time up into day intervals
fooList.GroupBy(f => f.Time.Date)

// splitting time up into month intervals
fooList.GroupBy(f => f.Time.Date.AddDays(-f.Time.Day))
```

If you really do want to map all of the same hour/day/month into the same group then it's easier.

Answer (score 2):

Hour is a property of DateTime, so it should be as simple as:

```
fooList.GroupBy(f => f.Hour)
```

That would give you an `IGrouping<int, Foo>` object, in which the int key is the hour.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using query expression.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FooDate { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>()
{
    new Foo() { FooID = 1, FooDate = new DateTime(2010,3,15,18,30,0)},
    new Foo() { FooID = 2, FooDate = new DateTime(2010,3,15,19,30,0)},
    new Foo() { FooID = 3, FooDate = new DateTime(2010,3,15,20,30,0)},
    new Foo() { FooID = 4, FooDate = new DateTime(2010,3,15,18,15,0)},
    new Foo() { FooID = 5, FooDate = new DateTime(2010,3,15,18,45,0)},
    new Foo() { FooID = 6, FooDate = new DateTime(2010,3,15,20,15,0)},
    new Foo() { FooID = 7, FooDate = new DateTime(2010,3,15,19,15,0)}
};

var query = from foo in foos
            group foo by foo.FooDate.Hour
                into foogroup
                select new
                {
                    Hour = foogroup.Key,
                    Foos = foos.Where(foo => foo.FooDate.Hour == foogroup.Key)
                };

foreach (var group in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Hour);
    foreach (Foo foo in group.Foos)
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", foo.FooID, foo.FooDate);
}
```

Edit: Regarding the need to seperate days, months, etc., you can extend your grouping like the following

```
var query = from foo in foos
            group foo by new { Date = foo.FooDate.Date, Hour = foo.FooDate.Hour }
                into foogroup
                select new
                {
                    Date = foogroup.Key.Date,
                    Hour = foogroup.Key.Hour,
                    Foos = foos.Where(foo => 
                        foo.FooDate.Date == foogroup.Key.Date 
                        && foo.FooDate.Hour == foogroup.Key.Hour)
                };
```